# Cannot retrieve data from MS SQL Server into QlikView application using ODBC connection

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, qlikview

There are three machines:

- Server
- My local computer
- Colleague's computer

(all three are different physical machines)
On Server an on my computer I set up the ODBC connection to SQL Server Database.
From these two machines the connection is functioning ie application can retrieve the data.
Furthermore, when I connect with Mgmt Studio with the ODBC User, I can see the data.
However the colleage is having problems with connection.
With the application (QlikView) she gets following error msg: "Table not found..."
The second error msg, when she tries to see the data with Mgmt Studio, is: "the execute permission was denied on the object 'sp_enable_sql_debug'..."

In addition, the same DB user (Credentials) is used by all of us on all the mentioned machine. We have no idea what the problem is, and where to look for. Does anybody have any advice?

Comment: If I recall correctly, I watched a webinar on Qlikview and the host mentioned that you use an OLE connection to connect to a MS SQL Server, I am not sure if that will help. Have you tested the connection to the SQL server using Qlikview from your local computer, or different users?

Answer (score 2):

As Scheballs write you want to avoid using ODBC. OLE DB provides the exact same options.

From the error message it sounds that you a permission issue.

When you create the OLE DB/ODBC Connection, you have the option to embed the credentials, in an encrypted format in to the connection string.

If you embed them, the other users will get the same permission as the ODBC user, if not they get the permissions that there AD account has.

Comment: Thanks @seebach I knew there was a good reason for the OLE connection being used. Also thank you because I did not know that about ODBC user permissions.

Comment: Please confirm if I understood correctly - the problem is because I made ODBC and not OLE DB Connection? The reason is because ODBC connections are making permission issues. If I make OLE DB connection - everything should work?

Comment: Adam, the ODBC connections requires you to setup a connection for each user in ControlPanel > Adminstrator Tools > ODBC before you can use it. OLE DB does not need this pre configuration.